# Example of DAO Factory whose datasource is not going to change across the different versions

Tags: java, dao

Here is the diagram which represents the structure of DAO Factory whose dataStorage is not going to be changed across the different versions:

[image]

My question is about the example of an implementation. Assume we have two different `DAO`s

`UserDAO`

```
public interface UserDAO{
    //CRUD operations and something else
}
```

`PaymentsDAO`

```
public interface PaymentsDAO{
    //CRUD operations and something else  
}
```

Now we have two Implementations of the `DAO`s:

`UserDAOImpl`

```
public interface UserDAOImpl{
    DataSource dataSource;
    //Implementation of the operations
}
```

`PaymentsDAOImpl`

```
public interface PaymentsDAOImpl{
    DataSource dataSource;
    //Implementation of the operations
}
```

Now we're creating a new class, called `DAOFactory`:

```
public abstract class DAOFactory{
    UserDAO userDAO;
    PaymentsDAO paymentsDAO;

    public abstract getUserDAO();
    public abstract getPaymentDAO();
}
```

So, now if we have a BusinessObject, say PaymentService, we just add a DAOFactory as a field and use it right? But why do we ever need to incapsulate all `DAO`'s into a factory? Wouldn't it be more simple if we jsut added neccessary `DAO`-objects as properties into the `BusinessObject`?

Comment: you must be creating DAO at runtime with some parameters to it and getting DAO based on that data. Basically you are taking advantage of polymorphism.

Comment: I think you should inject the Dao to the service, not the daofactory. Use dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dependency injection, your service has minimal coupling and no knowledge of the dao factory.

```
    DaoFactory daoFactory = new RdbDaoFactory(dataSource);

    myPaymentService.setUserDao(daoFactory.getUserDAO());
    myPaymentService.setPaymentDao(daoFactory.getPaymentDAO());
```

Encapsulating all the dao's into a factory gives you a central point for instantiating them, and is easily switched in future if your persistence layer changes.

Your last point about isn't it better to use Dao's in the business object (rather than factories) is correct, and I hope my example illustrates this for you.

Comment: So it's not neccessary to explcitily create RdbDaoFactory as in tour example. We could just add @Inject annotation and declare the corresponding bean within an IoC container. Right?

Answer (score 1):

By encapsulating all of the DAOs in a separate factory you are allowing your `BusinessObject` to not worry about the DAOs.

Let's assume one DAO is a hammer.

Let's assume the other DAO is a screwdriver.

Let's assume your `BusinessObject` is a carpenter who builds tables.

Your carpenter doesn't need to know anything how the hammer or the screwdriver is made or what materials were used to manufacture them, at some points he just needs the

`thatOneThingWhichScrewsTheScrewsIn()`

or

`thatOtherThingWhichCanBeUsedToDriveNailsIn()`

When he needs those, he knows a guy.

This guy will hook him up with exactly what he needs.

This guy is the tool guy.

This guy is the DAO factory.